# How to have two separate arrays show up next to each other. One is a normal array and the other one is 2d

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to coding and we started getting to arrays and 2d arrays. We were given a task to make a week calendar with 5 separate services and how much in a day they were used. The problem I'm having is that I cannot for the life of me figure out how can I get the 5 services inputted by the user next to the 2d array in the terminal. the output I'm getting is this. so i basically need the services and the different values next to each other.

service1

service2

service3

service4

service5

```
Ma      Ti      Ke      To      Pe      La      Su
 1       1       1       1       1       1       1
 1       1       1       1       1       1       1
 1       1       1       1       1       1       1
 1       1       1       1       1       1       1
 1       1       1       1       1       1       1
```

PS C:\Code with java vs>

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//Import the scanner

public class harkka6_3 {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        int sum = 0;
        //Base were the sum is calculated
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Give names of five services.");
        //Ask for the names of the services
        
        String[] table  = new String [5];
        //Create a new array for the services
        int[][] table2d = new int[5][7];
        //Make a 2d array for the service data
        double[] taulukko_summa =new double[table2d[0].length];
        //Make an array for the sum of all the columns

        for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Give a service");
            table[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        //Asks for the services from the user

        System.out.println("Give the values for the array");
        //Ask for the arrays values

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){

                table2d[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                sum += table2d[i][j];

            }
        }
        //Ask for the 2d arrays values from the users

        for(String i : table){

            System.out.print("\n" + i + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        //Print out the values from the first array

        String daysoftheweek = "Mo\t" + "Tu\t" + "Wed\t" + "Thu\t" + "Fri\t" + "Sa\t" + "Su\t";
        System.out.println(daysoftheweek);
        //Create and print out the days for the week

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
                
                System.out.print(" " + table2d[i][j] + "\t");
                taulukko_summa[j] += table2d[i][j];
                
              
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
              
        }
        //Print out the values for the 2d array and also sum up all the values in the 2d array

        System.out.println("Taulukon summa on " + sum);
        //Print out the sum of the whole 2d array

        for (int sarake = 0; sarake < taulukko[0].length; sarake++) {
            int sarakesum = 0;
            for (int rivi = 0; rivi < taulukko.length; rivi++) {
                sarakesum += taulukko[rivi][sarake];
            }
            System.out.println("Palveluiden Sarakkeiden yhteenlasku  " + sarake + " on: " + sarakesum);
        }
        //sum up all the data from each seperate column and print out the result

        input.close();
        //Close the scanner

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Seems like the post didnt show propely the terminal. it just supposed to be a 5x7 matrice of just 1's

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by printing the services (table array) inside the double loop.

**Remove this loop.**

```
for(String i : table){
    System.out.print("\n" + i + "\n");
}
```

**Update string daysoftheweek as the following:**

```
String daysoftheweek = "Service\t" + "Mo\t" + "Tu\t" + "Wed\t" + "Thu\t" + "Fri\t" + "Sa\t" + "Su\t";
```

**Update the double loop as the following:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.print(table[i] + "\t");
    for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        
        System.out.print(" " + table2d[i][j] + "\t");
        taulukko_summa[j] += table2d[i][j];
        
      
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
      
}
```